# Does POI provide an Event-Driven API to read XLS and XLSX Files?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hopefully the title says it all. I understand that the newer 'SS' model supports both XLS and XLSX format files, but it doesn't seem to have an event-driven implementation, as far as I can see :-(

I only want to read the files, not write them, and I only really need the cell contents and their data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and No!

Apache POI does provide ways to read the two Excel file formats in a streaming, low memory, event-driven way

However... Because the two file formats are stored in very different ways (one is bits of XML held within a zip file, the other is binary records), it isn't possible to read both formats in an event way with the same code.

Your options are therefore to buy some more memory + use the UserModel approach which hides the differences by providing common interfaces, or write two lots of Event code to handle the two different formats

For XLS files / HSSF, you should follow the [Apache POI docs on the HSSF Event API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api).

For XLSX files / XSSF, you should follow the [Apache POI docs on the XSSF SAX Event API](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api)

Various examples of both of those in use can be found in the Apache POI source and examples.

Comment: In the end I decided to bite the bullet and go for the simpler UserModel approach. I handle both types of file by the dumb approach of trying to open one type and catching the exception if one is raised and opening the 'other' type if so. Shame there can't be a common event model :-(

Comment: [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) handles opening the right UserModel for you! A common event form isn't really possible, as the event way works very close to the file format, and the underlying formats are very different

Comment: @Gagravarr ... you seems to be everywhere in POI :). Kudos to you.

Comment: @Gagravarr
Please answer this if you can
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57512192/unable-to-understand-even-model-of-poi-api-for-reading-excel-files-xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Apache POI event driven reading is available:

Please see this link: [how-to-event-reading](https://poi.apache.org/poifs/how-to.html#reading_event)

> As stated: `org.apache.poi.poifs.eventfilesystem.POIFSReaderListener`
>   is an interface used to register for documents. When a matching
>   document is read by the
>   `org.apache.poi.poifs.eventfilesystem.POIFSReader`, the
>   `POIFSReaderListener` instance receives an
>   `org.apache.poi.poifs.eventfilesystem.POIFSReaderEvent` instance,
>   which contains an open `DocumentInputStream` and information about the
>   document.

For your getting start:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException
{
    final String filename = args[0];
    POIFSReader r = new POIFSReader();
    r.registerListener(new MyPOIFSReaderListener());
    r.read(new FileInputStream(filename));
}

static class MyPOIFSReaderListener implements POIFSReaderListener
{
    public void processPOIFSReaderEvent(final POIFSReaderEvent event)
    {
        final POIFSDocumentPath path = event.getPath();
        final String name = event.getName();
        final DocumentInputStream stream = event.getStream();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Garry :-) - out of curiosity, why was my original question edited to removed the 'Thanks for any help :-)'? Is politeness considered improper on SO?

Comment: @Andy .. its not improper. For me its fine, your words should show your politeness and not the actual thanks word. But some are against it and thinks that it should be removed. Check this meta post [should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: Thanks for a courteous reply Garry, whic was more than I was expecting tbh. Looked at the link and I'm still surprised that simple courtesies are *so* frowned upon. Guess SO must be staffed by 'Noi Yoikers'. Still amused that ppl have the time to delete such comments :-)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still getting the 'invalid format' message even when using the POIFS listener approach (can't remember the actual error message here). Looks like I'll have to investigate Gagravarr's suggestion - which involves more work unfortunately and is (arguably) less elegant.