# Unable to understand Even model of POI API for reading Excel files(.xlsx)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, sax

I have been using the User model of POI API for reading excel files(.xlsx) until I encountered the out of memory(GC Overhead) exception as I was processing a pretty big file.

Upon some analysis, I was suggested to use the Event model(XSSF SAX Event API) rather of the same POI API. The problem is I am unable to understand the howto of this API by reading the docs. I did not have any problem while trying to understand the User model which I am using now. I know this Event model requires some understanding of the low lying mechanism of how these files are stored as the docs itself states:

```
This is intended for intermediate developers who are willing to learn a little bit of low level structure of .xlsx files, and who are happy processing XML in java. Its relatively simple to use, but requires a basic understanding of the file structure. The advantage provided is that you can read a XLSX file with a relatively small memory footprint.
```

Unforfortunately I dont have that level of understanding of excel files or the API and dont know where and how to start either.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well nobody will write you a book about SAX and XML parsing in an answer here. So read about those topics and try understand the examples in [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api). Or try using [Excel Streaming Reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader). This syntactically is near by the apache poi usermodel code.

Comment: @AxelRichter
Yeah I understand. From where do you suggest I read about them. The docs(link you shared) seems not very helpful for a noobie

Comment: If you wants learn: At first understand that `*.xlsx` files are simply `ZIP` archives. You can unzip a `*.xlsx` file and have a look at the `*.xml` files in it. Once you know the `XML`, you have a clue about what to parse. Then do using `SAX and XML parsing` as search keywords to ask the internet. You will find tutorials about this topics. I personally prefer `StAX`. There are [answers from mine about this topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3915431+stax).

Comment: If you wants fast results: Try using [Excel Streaming Reader](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader). This syntactically is nearby the apache poi usermodel code.

Comment: Read the source code of one of the many examples that Apache POI ships which make use of it?